# How to create an array of object literals in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

I need to create an array of object literals like this:

```
var myColumnDefs = [
    {key:"label", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
    {key:"notes", sortable:true,resizeable:true},......
```

In a loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < oFullResponse.results.length; i++) {
    console.log(oFullResponse.results[i].label);
}
```

The value of `key` should be `results[i].label` in each element of the array.

Answer (score 454, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
var len = oFullResponse.results.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push({
        key: oFullResponse.results[i].label,
        sortable: true,
        resizeable: true
    });
}
```

Comment: calculating length only once is probably a good idea, I choose to add a `var obj` to make the code clearer, of course you can skip it, you can write the whole script in one line if you wish :)

Comment: @Triptych - Yes, but it's a property lookup that you execute with each iteration, which isn't free and can be avoided.  Micro-optimization?  Possibly. Also, it is a "live" value - if you modify the array in the loop, the length will change on successive iterations which could lead to infinity. Give this a watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU

Comment: Yeah, but you're not modifying the array each iteration.  If you were, it would be ridiculous to compare against length anyway in most cases.

Comment: Why arr becomes an object? Does js can has array of objects like array, not like object? https://jsfiddle.net/91cgc4zu/

Comment: I like the pattern of getting length outside the loop.  Even though it may not matter here, it's a good habit to get into for the cases (and other languages) where it does matter.

Comment: @fdrv Not sure if you still need a reply to this, but where does `arr` “become” an object? It’s always an object to begin with. A JS Array can have any value inside.

Answer (score 62):

RaYell's answer is good - it answers your question.

It seems to me though that you should really be creating an object keyed by labels with sub-objects as values:

```
var columns = {};
for (var i = 0; i < oFullResponse.results.length; i++) {
    var key = oFullResponse.results[i].label;
    columns[key] = {
        sortable: true,
        resizeable: true
    };
}

// Now you can access column info like this. 
columns['notes'].resizeable;
```

The above approach should be much faster and idiomatic than searching the entire object array for a key for each access.

Comment: +1 since the key solution, makes more sense and help me with my needs:)

Comment: it looks like you are missing a semi-colon after you set the var key?

Comment: nice answer, been looking for how to access the information for a while, thank you

Comment: what if key need to be more than once ! ['notes'] can occur more than once then what can we do?

Comment: Milson - in that case, it's not really a "key"

Answer (score 39):

You can do something like that in ES6.

```
new Array(10).fill().map((e,i) => {
   return {idx: i}
});
```

Answer (score 22):

This is what [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) are good at

```
var arr = oFullResponse.results.map(obj => ({
    key: obj.label,
    sortable: true,
    resizeable: true
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
 var myColumnDefs = new Object();
 for (var i = 0; i < oFullResponse.results.length; i++) {
     myColumnDefs[i] = ({key:oFullResponse.results[i].label, sortable:true, resizeable:true});
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the same idea of Nick Riggs but I create a constructor, and a push a new object in the array by using it. It avoid the repetition of the keys of the class:

```
var arr = [];
var columnDefs = function(key, sortable, resizeable){
    this.key = key; 
    this.sortable = sortable; 
    this.resizeable = resizeable;
    };

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push((new columnDefs(oFullResponse.results[i].label,true,true)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go even further than @tetra with ES6 you can use the [Object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and do something like this:

```js
const john = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };
const people = new Array(10).fill().map((e, id) => ({ ...john, id }));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create the array and then append the object literals to it.

```
var myColumnDefs = [];

for ( var i=0 ; i < oFullResponse.results.length; i++) {

    console.log(oFullResponse.results[i].label);
    myColumnDefs[myColumnDefs.length] = {key:oFullResponse.results[i].label, sortable:true, resizeable:true};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myColumnDefs = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < oFullResponse.results.length; i++) {
    myColumnDefs.push({key:oFullResponse.results[i].label, sortable:true, resizeable:true});
}
```

Comment: It's better to init an array using `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Comment: Interesting discussion [] vs. new Array() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array